# Topological manifold example

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

$\theta(x,x^2)=x$

$\Bbb X =${$(x,x^2)| x$ in $\Bbb R$}

And V is subset of $\Bbb R$

$dim\Bbb X=1$

My instructor said that this is topological manifold.

Why?

Please can you explain me? This example is from my notebook. But there is No explanation except for this. Thank you for help.

Comment: What have you tried? I recomend you to read the definition of topological manifold and check point by point that $\mathbb{X}$ satisfies them.

Comment: I know that a topological space $(X,\Bbb T)$ be a topological manifold of dim $n$ if $(X,\Bbb T)$ is hausdroff, second countable and locally euclidean space of dim $n$. I guess I need to check these three parts accourding to what you said. Well, how can I check these? Please can you show me? I understand these definitions. But I cannot apply on an example. These definitions is so abstract for me. So please help me @IasafroMaesman

Comment: Before giving an answer, I will try to help you. First, see that we are considering in $\mathbb{X}$ the topology inheritated by the inclusion in $\mathbb{R}^2$ -obviously, as it is not in other manner stated we assumed that $\mathbb{R}^2$ has the usual euclidean topology. From there, what can you say about topological properties inheritated by this topological subspace?

Comment: Thank you for help:) yes. Thus, the definition of the third part has been already proved. Now we need to 1st and 2nd parts. @IasafroMaesman that's we need to show second countablity and being hausdroff

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand the last you said? @IasafroMaesman

Comment: No, the thing that has been proven is that $\mathbb{X}$ is Hausdorff and that $\mathbb{X}$ is second countable. (These properties are always inheritated by subspaces.) That $\mathbb{X}$ is locally euclidean is usually the hard part, but here is easy, since $\mathbb{X}$ is just a parabola -and this have to give you the idea that in this case $\mathbb{X}$ is not just locally euclidean but homeomorphic to whole $\mathbb{R}$ and one more hint the homeomosphism is $\theta$-.

Comment: For examples, if you joint an intersecting pair of straight lines that space would be Hausdorff and second countable, but not locally euclidean at the intersection point. Since if you quit the intersection point you get four connected components locally, which does not happen in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Okay I have understood. Thanks @IasafroMaesman

Comment: This may be inappropriate, and I'll delete the comment if necessary, but I feel compelled to say something about (from a comment by B11b) "I understand the definitions. But I cannot apply on an example. These definitions is so abstract for me." I believe that, if a definition is too abstract for you to apply on an example, then unless the example is absurdly complicated, you do not understand the definition. I fear you may have a concept of "understanding" that is OK in some contexts but just won't work in mathematics. Examples are an essential part of understanding.

Answer (score 1):

We know that : The Graph of a smooth function is a manifolds.
For a subset of $A ⊂ \mathbb R^n$ and a function
$f : A→\mathbb R^m$, the graph of $f$ is defined to be the subset 
$$G( f ) = \{(x, f (x)) ∈ A×\mathbb R^m\}$$
If $U $is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and $f : U →\mathbb R^n$ is $C^{\infty}$, then the two maps
$$f : G( f )→U$$   $$(x, f (x)) \mapsto  x$$
and
$$(1, f ) : U →G( f )$$$$ x \mapsto (x, f (x))$$
are continuous and inverse to each other, and so are homeomorphisms. The graph
$G( f )$ of a $C^{\infty}$ function $f : U →\mathbb R^m$ has an atlas with a single chart $(G( f ),f )$, and is
therefore a $C^{\infty}$ manifold. This shows that many of the familiar surfaces of calculus,
for example your question are maniflods .

Answer (score 0):

Check that $\theta:X \to\mathbb{R}$ it's an homeomorphism, where $\mathbb{R}$ has the euclidean topology; then you conclude since the codomain is surely a one-dimensional topological manifold.